# Java Validation - method parameter name from ConstraintViolation.getPropertyPath() is returning sporadic values

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I'm using the following example from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-method-constraints.html.

However, the parameterNode.getName() sometimes returns 'arg0' and other times returns the actual method parameter name like 'clientId'. It keeps switching back and forth in consecutive runs. I'm totally confused and unable to write test cases. Any help here please?

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> violations = executableValidator.validateParameters(
        object,
        method,
        parameterValues
);

assertEquals( 1, violations.size() );
Iterator<Node> propertyPath = violations.iterator()
        .next()
        .getPropertyPath()
        .iterator();

MethodNode methodNode = propertyPath.next().as( MethodNode.class );
assertEquals( "drive", methodNode.getName() );
assertEquals( Arrays.<Class<?>>asList( int.class ), methodNode.getParameterTypes() );

ParameterNode parameterNode = propertyPath.next().as( ParameterNode.class );
assertEquals( "arg0", parameterNode.getName() );
assertEquals( 0, parameterNode.getParameterIndex() );
```

Comment: I get this as well, but in my case it is always argX.  Code is compiled with parameter names stored in the class files :(

If you get this sometimes but other times not, and you're using Eclipse + Maven, check that both of the compilers are set to store parameters in class files (Java 8 feature).

Comment: As described in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-parameter-name-provider configuring with ReflectionParameterNameProvider might help. Your might also provide own implementation (for instance based annotations or types).